# How to get a list of dictionary in a single column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, group-by

Hi I have a dataframe in 1NF form which I wanted to change to different format where I can access those values.

This is how my dataframe looks like

| Code | ProvType | Alias | spec_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A12 | A | Hi | 1 |
| 1A12 | B | Hi | 2 |
| 1A12 | B | Hola | 2 |
| 1A12 | A | Pola | 3 |
| 1b32 | C | Cola | 7 |
| 1b32 | D | Cola | 6 |
| 1b32 | A | Mola | 1 |

| Code | aliasList |
| --- | --- |
| 1A12 | [{alias:Hi,provtypelist:[A,B],specCodeList:[1,2]},{alias:Hola,provtypelist:[B],specCodeList:[1]},{alias:Pola,provtypelist:[A],specCodeList:[3]}] |
| 1b32 | [{alias:Cola,provtypelist:[C,D],specCodeList:[7,6]},{alias:Mola,provtypelist:[A],specCodeList:[1]}] |

I want my dataframe to look like this. Dont know how the code/groupby will look like so any help is appreciated in this.

The reason i want my dataframe to look like this is so that I can insert that aliasList column into opensearch index with nested datatype.

Another way will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
out = (
  # first aggregate ProvType/spec_code to lists
  df.groupby(['Code', 'Alias'], as_index=False).agg(list)
  # then convert to dictionary per Code
   .groupby('Code').apply(lambda g: g.drop(columns='Code').to_dict('records'))
   .reset_index(name='aliasList')
)
```

Output:

```
   Code                                                                                                                                                                       aliasList
0  1A12  [{'Alias': 'Hi', 'ProvType': ['A', 'B'], 'spec_code': [1, 2]}, {'Alias': 'Hola', 'ProvType': ['B'], 'spec_code': [2]}, {'Alias': 'Pola', 'ProvType': ['A'], 'spec_code': [3]}]
1  1b32                                                        [{'Alias': 'Cola', 'ProvType': ['C', 'D'], 'spec_code': [7, 6]}, {'Alias': 'Mola', 'ProvType': ['A'], 'spec_code': [1]}]
```

First list at index 0 for clarity:

```
[{'Alias': 'Hi', 'ProvType': ['A', 'B'], 'spec_code': [1, 2]},
 {'Alias': 'Hola', 'ProvType': ['B'], 'spec_code': [2]},
 {'Alias': 'Pola', 'ProvType': ['A'], 'spec_code': [3]}]
```

Comment: It does not solve my problem. It has code also in the dictionary and i dont want code.

Comment: @BrownBatman yes of course, just `drop` in the `apply` (you could also slice the wanted columns)